BRIN index for paginated queries
I have a large static table.
With "large", I mean 1.000.000.000 rows.
And "static" means no Inserts/Updates/Deletes are allowed. Just Selects
I'm always going to filter with "equal" operator by the index key
and that query could return 1 or a few (2, as much) million rows
(800 rows in average)
I think a BRIN fits very well here
Of course I have to try it. However, I need to look further
because the queries will be issued by a web application.
The application must show result in a paginated fashion of -we say- 20 rows each page (through LIMIT and OFFSET clauses):
select * from my_table where id= xxx OFFSET 15000 LIMIT 20;

I think BRIN fits perfectly. But I can't realize, a priori
if the pagination will benefit from the BRIN.
UPDATE It seems I can't CLUSTER using a BRIN index...

My conclusion
Finally I'll be using BTREE

and a bit better, if data is sorted

With "sorted" I mean that I'm populating the table from Azure sorted dataflow through the "COPY method", a method that -as far as I've read- preserves order

Check your query plan, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). Without that information it's next to impossible to help you

ok, soon I'll start the tests

I couldn't make CLUSTER work with the BRIN index. It's seems not compatible (?). So I did it with a BTREE, and I got this:

Limit  (cost=2419.63..21291.14 rows=5000 width=144) (actual time=11.517..58.475 rows=5000 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on bets  (cost=721.19..244526.01 rows=64596 width=144) (actual time=11.436..58.031 rows=5450 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ("client_id" = 142413)
Heap Blocks: exact=95
->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_stage_bets  (cost=0.00..705.05 rows=64596 width=0) (actual time=10.622..10.622 rows=365290 loops=1)
Index Cond: ("client_id" = 142413)
Planning Time: 0.093 ms
Execution Time: 58.726 ms

explain analyze select * from history where client_id= 142413 offset 450 limit 5000;
very high-speed in my opinion

58 milliseconds, not too bad

A BRIN index on id will only help with this query if id is ever-increasing (later inserts will have a higher value than previous ones) or ever-decreasing, and if you never update or delete rows in the table.
If the table is read-only, you can rewrite it in such an order by creating a B-tree index, running CLUSTER to rewrite the table, then dropping the B-tree index and creating a BRIN index instead. But if you already have a B-tree index.
If the table is sorted properly, the BRIN index will speed up the query, in that it will pinpoint those ranges of 128 blocks that contain the data you need. However, it will be quite a bit less efficient than a B-tree index.
Another downside is that a BRIN index won't help with ORDER BY, so that PostgreSQL will still have to sort.
If you paginate with OFFSET, fetching later pages is never going to be efficient, so it won't get any worse with a BRIN index. If you were to choose the better keyset pagination method, a BRIN index could not support it effectively.
All in all, if you have a large table that is physically ordered in the correct way and never changes, a BRIN index will help. It won't be as fast as a B-tree index, though.

yes, right, I forgot to mention my concern about the ORDER BY
